# Java Swing Breadcrumb component?

Tags: java, swing, breadcrumbs

Anyone know of any active library that has breadcrumb view for Java Swing? I found http://java.net/projects/flamingo/ but not sure if that is still actively being developed.

basically I want to achieve the breadcrumb view that is available in Eclipse.

Comment: Why do you care about the project activity if all you want is to use the library? What's wrong with the flamingo project?

Comment: Why don't you care about the project activity for continued support and updates? What's wrong with the flamingo project is that there are no downloads available.

Comment: the successor of substance is called Insubstantial and is actively maintained by Danno Ferrin (don't know how active the Flamingo part is, though) see http://insubstantial.posterous.com

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliJ Idea Java IDE is written in Swing and the open-source part of it has a breadcrumb component.

Alternatively JIDE has a commercial breadcrumb component: [documentation](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/navigation/BreadcrumbBar.html), [homepage](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/component.htm)

Answer (score 0):

WebLAF does: http://weblookandfeel.com

Other LAF's that are excellent that might include breadcrumb components are JTattoo, and Substance